# Why does the API doc for InteractsWithPages not include a lot of the functions available if you view it in the laravel/framework repo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

The official framework repo's [page for InteractsWithPages](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/InteractsWithPages.php) has a lot of functions that [the API documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/InteractsWithPages.html) does not cover. Why is this? It's sort of made the documentation seem unreliable to me, meaning I have to go search the github every time I want more information about a certain function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation you have included only methods that are `public` because in most cases you will use only them.

If you need to extend any class/trait you will need to look at code so you will look at protected/private methods and their code so they don't need to be included in documentation

Comment: An example here is the $this->type() function which gets used a lot in functional PHPUnit testing. It's listed as protected, but is the type() function of InteractsWithPages not the function being called when I use $this->type()? [See Laravel docs for what I am refering to if you need to](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#interacting-with-your-application)